# spacy NOT_IN attribute

Tags: regex, spacy

I have a text

```
ADDRESS_ID NAME ADDRESS CATEGORY_ID FIRST_NAME DAILY_ACTIVE
```

I want to find out tokens like

```
NAME ADDRESS FIRST_NAME
```

And I want to ignore all the tokens with 'ID', 'ACTIVE' and so on into it.

So i used spacy-

here line.rstrip() is reading all the allowed tokens from a file. eg- Name, Address

```
 newPattern = [{"LOWER": line.rstrip()}]
 newPattern2 = [{"LOWER": {"NOT_IN":["ID"], "REGEX": "[_]{}".format(line.rstrip())}}]
 newPattern3 = [{"LOWER": {"REGEX": "{}[_]".format(line.rstrip()), "NOT_IN":["ID"]}}]
```

Its giving out put like this

```
ADDRESS_ID
NAME
ADDRESS
FIRST_NAME
```

But I am not able to ignore the tokens with ID into it. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `spacy`, but I think you could try to use [word boundary](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-regex/python-regex-word-boundary/) in your regex. Hope below snippet could give you the idea to implement it in `spacy`

```
import re

txt  = "ADDRESS_ID NAME ADDRESS CATEGORY_ID FIRST_NAME DAILY_ACTIVE"
line = " NAME ADDRESS FIRST_NAME "
line = r"\b" + line.strip().replace(" ", r"\b|") + r"\b"
matches = re.findall(line, txt, re.IGNORECASE)
print("- search text: " + line)
print("- search pattern: " + line)
print('- matched result:', *matches, sep='\n  + ')
```

See demo [here](https://www.online-python.com/ikCs7LDMp9)

Answer (score 0):

If your actual patterns are like `"ID"`:

`LOWER` is going to match again the lowercase form of the input token, so you also need to use lowercase in the pattern strings, e.g. `{"LOWER": {"NOT_IN": ["id"]}}`.

`{"LOWER": {"NOT_IN": ["ID"]}}` will match every token because no lowercase token is ever `"ID"`.